# Sorting a 2D array, numbers should be consecutive

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d

I made a 2D array which looks like this as now:

```
(3,0)
(0,1)
(3,1)
(0,2)
(3,2)
(0,3)
(1,3)
(2,3)
(3,3)
```

The problem is, I want to know how to sort a two-dimensional array so it'll result like this:

```
(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
(0,3)
(1,3)
(2,3)
(3,3)
(3,2)
(3,1)
(3,0)
```

Where every coordinate has at least one same number from before or after the coordinate.

EDIT:

I'd like to apologize for short information. Anyway, I tried the code by @khaled_gomaa and it didn't give the output that I wanted, but I appreciate his help!

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

```
public class Asdf {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int[][] data = new int[][] { new int[] { 0, 0 },
                new int[] { 3, 0 }, new int[] { 0, 1 }, new int[] { 3, 1 },
                new int[] { 0, 2 }, new int[] { 3, 2 }, new int[] { 0, 3 },
                new int[] { 1, 3 }, new int[] { 2, 3 }, new int[] { 3, 3 } };

        for (int[] indiv : data) {
            System.out.println("(" + indiv[0] + "," + indiv[1] + ")");
        }

        Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<int[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final int[] entry1, final int[] entry2) {
                if (entry1[0] == entry2[0]) {
                    if (entry1[1] > entry2[1]) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (entry1[0] > entry2[0]) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int indiv[] = data[i];
            System.out.println("(" + indiv[0] + "," + indiv[1] + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
(0,3)
(1,3)
(2,3)
(3,0)
(3,1)
(3,2)
(3,3)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I needed to do something shortly after this so I had to rush this, which is why there's only small information in my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Asdf {

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final int[][] data = new int[][]{
    new int[] {3,0},
    new int[] {0,1},
    new int[] {3,1},
    new int[] {0,2},
    new int[] {3,2},
    new int[] {0,3},
    new int[] {1,3},
    new int[] {2,3},
    new int[] {3,3}
    };

    Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(final int[] entry1, final int[] entry2) {
            if(entery1[0] == entry2[0]){
              if(entery1[1] > entery2[1])
                return 1;
              else
                return -1;
            }
            else{
              if(entery1[0] > entery2[0])
                return 1;
              else
                return -1;
            }

            final String time2 = entry2[0];
            return time1.compareTo(time2);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: The output in your code didn't match what I wanted. Nevertheless, I wanted to thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

why not make 2 single-dimensional arrays and then....compare each individually?

After that you should just put them together and create one 2d array.

I am saying this because it seems that you are comparing the "columns" individually anyways. What I mean to say is that you are not keeping the coordinates in each index together. Your data from each column is separated anyways.

Answer (score 0):

This sorts it as you wish.

It uses a class called `TwoIntsForCompare`, which implements [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). It weights the index-zero value (which I'm calling "major") ten times greater than the "minor" (index 1) value.

```
class TwoIntsForCompare implements Comparable<TwoIntsForCompare>  {
   public final int major;
   public final int minor;
   public TwoIntsForCompare(int[] idx0Major_idx1Minor)  {
      this.major = idx0Major_idx1Minor[0];
      this.minor = idx0Major_idx1Minor[1];
   }
   public int compareTo(TwoIntsForCompare to_compareTo)  {
      return  (((major - to_compareTo.major) * 10) +
         (minor - to_compareTo.minor));
   }
   public int[] getArray()  {
      return  (new int[] {major, minor});
   }
}
```

After putting each sub-array into this object, they are inserted into a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) with does the sorting automatically, by using `TwoIntsForCompare`s `compareTo` function.

Main logic:

```
Map<TwoIntsForCompare,Object> twoIntsMap = new TreeMap<TwoIntsForCompare,Object>();
for(int i = 0; i < intArrArrOrig.length; i++)  {
   twoIntsMap.put(new TwoIntsForCompare(intArrArrOrig[i]), null);
}

int[][] intArrArrSorted = new int[intArrArrOrig.length][2];
Set<TwoIntsForCompare> tifcSet = twoIntsMap.keySet();
int idx = 0;
Iterator<TwoIntsForCompare> itrTifc = tifcSet.iterator();
while(itrTifc.hasNext())  {
   intArrArrSorted[idx++] = itrTifc.next().getArray();
}
```

Full code:

```
import  java.util.Set;
import  java.util.Iterator;
import  java.util.TreeMap;
import  java.util.Map;
/**
   <P>{@code java SortArrayOfTwoInts}</P>
 **/
public class SortArrayOfTwoInts  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
      int[][] intArrArrOrig = new int[][]  {
         new int[] {3,0},
         new int[] {0,1},
         new int[] {3,1},
         new int[] {0,2},
         new int[] {3,2},
         new int[] {0,3},
         new int[] {1,3},
         new int[] {2,3},
         new int[] {3,3}};

      System.out.println("Original:");
      for(int i = 0; i < intArrArrOrig.length; i++)  {
         System.out.println("[" + intArrArrOrig[i][0] + ", " + intArrArrOrig[i][3] + "]");
      }

      System.out.println();

      Map<TwoIntsForCompare,Object> twoIntsMap = new TreeMap<TwoIntsForCompare,Object>();
      for(int i = 0; i < intArrArrOrig.length; i++)  {
         twoIntsMap.put(new TwoIntsForCompare(intArrArrOrig[i]), null);
      }

      int[][] intArrArrSorted = new int[intArrArrOrig.length][2];
      Set<TwoIntsForCompare> tifcSet = twoIntsMap.keySet();
      int idx = 0;
      Iterator<TwoIntsForCompare> itrTifc = tifcSet.iterator();
      while(itrTifc.hasNext())  {
         intArrArrSorted[idx++] = itrTifc.next().getArray();
      }

      System.out.println("Sorted:");
      for(int i = 0; i < intArrArrSorted.length; i++)  {
         System.out.println("[" + intArrArrSorted[i][0] + ", " + intArrArrSorted[i][4] + "]");
      }
   }
}
class TwoIntsForCompare implements Comparable<TwoIntsForCompare>  {
   public final int major;
   public final int minor;
   public TwoIntsForCompare(int[] idx0Major_idx1Minor)  {
      this.major = idx0Major_idx1Minor[0];
      this.minor = idx0Major_idx1Minor[1];
   }
   public int compareTo(TwoIntsForCompare to_compareTo)  {
      return  (((major - to_compareTo.major) * 10) +
         (minor - to_compareTo.minor));
   }
   public int[] getArray()  {
      return  (new int[] {major, minor});
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java SortArrayOfTwoInts
Original:
[3, 0]
[0, 1]
[3, 1]
[0, 2]
[3, 2]
[0, 3]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[3, 3]

Sorted:
[0, 1]
[0, 2]
[0, 3]
[1, 3]
[2, 3]
[3, 0]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
```